# AirPlay service registered by `DNSServiceRegister` cannot be discovered by iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11, airplay

Multicast is disabled in our ethernet, so I registered proxy services (`_airplay._tcp` & `_raop._tcp`) pointed to Apple TV's IP with `DNSServiceRegister` in my app, register **and** detect the service on the same phone. It works fine in iOS 10, but my service can't be detected in Control Center in iOS 11.

Comment: Are you broadcasting from the iOS device <b>and</b> attempting to discover on the device as well?

Comment: @Viro Yes, it works on iOS 10

Answer (score 1):

When Apple changed around everything in iOS 11 (meaning AirPlay 2), they made it a tad more difficult for a device to Airplay to itself. You must use a much lower level API for this to work, by that I mean C instead of Objective-C.

Comment: This answer doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @sstn the answer requires some back and forth. We are actively emailing so I can properly help him instead of back and forth on stack.

Comment: Suggest you provide the solution here so that everyone can benefit.